# How to rebuild ng-repeat when track by value is changed?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I've got following ng-repeat expression:

```
ng-repeat="album in albums track by (album.id + gallery.layout)"
```

As you can see track by depends on album's id and gallery layout. When I change gallery layout nothing happens - looks like `ng-repeat` doesn't expect `track by` value change. To fix it I have to add/remove album (since layout was changed all items are updated).

How to force angular to update `ng-repeat`? I can select last album, remove it and add with `$timeout` but I don't like this solution.

Comment: calling $digest manually may help

Comment: no, it's not $digest problem

Answer (score 0):

If the Objects are truly different based on the gallery, one option would be to have a separate property for it. So your JS might look like:

```
$scope.$watch('gallery.layout', injectGalleryLayoutIds);

function injectGalleryLayoutIds(galleryLayout){
  $scope.albums.forEach(function(album){
    album.idForGallery = album.id + galleryLayout;
  });
}
```

And instead you would `track by idForGallery` .

If you want to avoid modifying the `album` Objects, you can use wrappers (of course, this will use some additional memory for every album):

```
$scope.$watch('gallery.layout', updateGalleryAlbums);

function updateGalleryAlbums(galleryLayout){
  $scope.galleryAlbums = $scope.albums.map(function(album){
    return { album: album, id: album.id + galleryLayout };
  });
}
```

**However**, I get the impression that the problem you're trying to solve might be better solved by either:

1) Pure CSS. Add a different class to a parent element with the layout name, and simply draw your items in as much detail is necessary. Show/hide the items, and restyle via CSS.

If the structure of the layouts is too different for the pure CSS approach to be feasible, another option might be:

2) Have directives or views for the different gallery layouts, `ng-switch` between them (or similarly inject the layout), and have `ng-repeat` inside their HTML, and simply `track by album.id`